# Random numbers generated by percentage of max value

Tags: python, random

I use the following approach to add a 50 numbers to my code

```
for i in range(0, 50):
    data = data.append({"describe_file": "This is the start of the story", "data_numbers": data.data_numbers.max() + np.random.randint(1000, 2000) }, ignore_index=True)`
```

I am trying to modify the code so instead of just adding random numbers between 1000-2000.
It should add in percentage, so lets say my max value is

```
data_numbers.max()
1000
```

I want to add random numbers that are for example `5%` bigger than the max value

Comment: So in your example youd want to add a number between 1000 and 1050 (+5%) ?

Comment: @tomgalpin,   1000+ 5-7% (of the max value which in this case it is 1000(

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the answer to what you're trying to say

```py
import pandas as pd
from random import uniform

def funct(data, a = 0.05, b = 1): # the default parameters correspond a range from 0.5% to 1%
  return round((max([n for n in data])) * (random.uniform(a, b))) # with uniform you can use float numbers to multiply and get the random porcentage of the max-value.

your_list = []
for i in range(0, 50):
  your_list.append(funct(data.data_numbers)))
```

With a list as sample data:

```py
data = [0, 1231, 3249, 69, 999, 12312, 12]
for i in range(0, 10):
  print(funct(data)) # remember that you can add a and b as your random percentage range.

1662
9049
3839
8732
9285
8752
8161
7039
9884
12068
```

I hope it solved your question.

Comment: If this helped you, remember to mark it as the correct answer.